# Changing the Hover style of a custom made shape in a sidebar nav

Tags: html, css

I designed a custom circle shape (with border) to accompany my sidebar nav link.

[image: img]

But am unable to create a desired hover style when hovered on, or active, as shown:

[image: desired]

```css
.sidebar-menu-dot {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #828282;
  margin-right: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#sidebar-menu .sidebar-menu-dot:hover,
#sidebar-menu .sidebar-menu-dot .active {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  background-color: #27A9F8;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  margin-right: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="metismenu">

  <ul>

    <li>
      <a href="home2.html" class="active">
        <span class="sidebar-menu-dot"></span>
        <span>Overview</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="sidebar-menu-dot"></span>
        <span>Student</span>
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the CSS properties I have added on the snippet. You can get that fancy hover effect just by applying some hover properties onto the `li:hover` tag.

```css
.sidebar-menu-dot {
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #828282;
    margin-right: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#sidebar-menu .sidebar-menu-dot:hover, #sidebar-menu .sidebar-menu-dot .active {
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    background-color: #27A9F8;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    margin-right: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.metismenu{
  width:50%;
}
span { /*ADDED*/
    color: gray;
    font-size:20px;
}
li{ /*ADDED*/
    padding: 10px;
}
li:hover { /*ADDED*/
    background-color: #27A9F8;
}
li:hover .sidebar-menu-dot { /*ADDED*/
    background-color: #27A9F8;
    border-color: white;
    color: white;
}
li:hover span { /*ADDED*/
    color: white;
}
ul { /*ADDED*/
    list-style: none;
}
a { /*ADDED*/
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="metismenu" id="sidebar-menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="active" href="home2.html">
                <span class="sidebar-menu-dot">
                </span>
                <span>
                    Overview
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span class="sidebar-menu-dot">
                </span>
                <span>
                    Student
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good place to start. You can take advantage of `psuedo class` to insert you're circles. This is a benefit in that, the user can not copy it / select it, if they ever needed to copy the text.

Just for reference, there is no real reason to put text inside of a `<span>` element if you aren't going to style it with the span. It's inherently inline.

```css
#sidebar-menu {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#sidebar-menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
#sidebar-menu li {
  width: 100%;
}
a:any-link {
 color: grey;
}
#sidebar-menu a {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#sidebar-menu a.active {
 color: white;
 background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
#sidebar-menu a:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 13px; height: 13px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #828282;
}
#sidebar-menu a.active:before {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border-color: white;
}



#sidebar-menu a:not(.active):hover,
#sidebar-menu a:not(.active):hover:before {
  background-color: #92b4f2;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="metismenu">

  <ul>

    <li>
      <a href="home2.html" class="active">
        Overview
      </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">
        Student
      </a>
    </li>


    <li>
      <a href="#">
        Teacher
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```